# How to convert a dataframe to JSON without the index?

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe output that I would like to convert to json, but it adds a leading zero, which gets added to the json. How do I remove it? Pandas by default numbers each row.

```
  id          version ... token                                type_id

0 10927076529 0       ... 56599bb6-3b56-425b-8688-8fc0c73fbedc 3
```

```
{"0":{"id":10927076529,"version":0,"token":"56599bb6-3b56-425b-8688-8fc0c73fbedc","type_id":3}}
```

```
df = df.rename(columns={'id': 'version', 'token': 'type_id' })
df2 = df.to_json(orient="index")
print(df2)
```

Comment: Try `df2 = df.to_json(orient="records")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has that 0 value as the row index for your single DataFrame entry. You can't remove it in the actual DataFrame as far as I know.

This is showing up in your JSON specifically because you're using the "index" option for the "orient" parameter.

If you want each row in your final dataframe to be a separate entry, you can try the "records" option instead of "index".

```
df2 = df.to_json(orient="records")
```

[This hyperlink](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/write-pandas-dataframe-to-json-file/) has a good illustration of the different options.

Another option you have is to set one of your columns as an index that you want to use, such as `id`/`version`. This will preserve a title, but without using the default indexing scheme provided by Pandas.

```
df = df.set_index('version')
df2 = df.to_json(orient="index")
```